# Ingesting MySQL data to GeoMesa analytics

Tags: mysql, geomesa

I am new to GeoMesa. I mean I just typed geomesa command. So, after following the command line tools tutorial on GeoMesa website. I found some information on ingesting data to geomesa through a .csv file.

> So, for my research:

- I have a MySQL database storing all the information sent from an Android Application.
- And I want to perform some geo spatial analytics on it.
- Right now I am converting my MySQL table to .csv file and then ingest it into geomesa as adviced on GeoMesa website.

> But my questions are:

- Is there any other better option because data is in GB and its a streaming data, hence I have to make .csv file regularly?
- Is there any API through which I can connect my MySQL database to geomesa?
- Is there any way to ingest using .sql dump file because that would be more easier then .csv file?

Comment: Do you know that mysql itself has data types and functions to perform spatial analysis? Otherwise all your questions are very broad.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with streaming data, I'd point to two GeoMesa integrations:

First, you might want to check out [NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/) for managing data flows.  If that fits into your architecture, then you can use [GeoMesa with NiFi](https://github.com/jahhulbert-ccri/geomesa-nifi).

Second, [Storm](https://storm.apache.org/) is quite popular for working with streaming data.  GeoMesa has a brief tutorial for Storm [here](https://github.com/geomesa/geomesa-tutorials/tree/master/geomesa-quickstart-storm).

Third, to ingest sql dumps directly, one option would be to extend the GeoMesa converter library to support them.  So far, we haven't had that as a feature request from a customer or a contribution to the project.  It'd definitely be a sensible and welcome extension!

I'd also point out the GeoMesa [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/locationtech/geomesa).  It can be useful for quicker responses.